# How come with google maps ios the info window isn't showing when I use a custom Icon?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm using a custom icon (a png of a house) and when this is clicked I expected an infowindow with the snippet and title to show but nothing happens when its clicked.

```
 func addMarker()
    {

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        let lat = 100
        let lng = 100
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
        marker.title = "myHouse"
        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "house")
        marker.snippet = "The snippet"
        marker.map = mapView

    }
```

I have semi-implemented the function below and when the marker is clicked it does print to the console.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool
    {

        print("click")
        return true

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return `false` in the delegate method, so that the map will continue with the default selection behavior. Have a look at `GMSMapView.h`:

```
/**
 * Called after a marker has been tapped.
 *
 * @param mapView The map view that was tapped.
 * @param marker The marker that was tapped.
 * @return YES if this delegate handled the tap event, which prevents the map from performing its
 * default selection behavior, and NO if the map should continue with its default selection
 * behavior.
 */
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
```